# How to await an if else statement with await statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, async-await

My function below has await statements inside an if else.

If i do this function, it will return [] an empty array since it isnt waiting for the if else statement to finish.

How do I wait for the if else statement to finsih?

```
const [imageArray, setImageArray] = useState();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

let a = 1
var array = [];
if(a === 2){
   array = await getArray();
} else if (a === 3){
   array = await getArray2();
}
setImageArray(array);
setLoading(false);

render(
{(!loading) ? (
       ......
```

Comment: Show the getArray() code as well

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan its just an async function that returns an array lets say [1,2,3]

Comment: Note that `if (a = 2)` will always go into the `if` block, because it **assigns** `2` to `a` and then tests the value of the result. Since 2 is truthy, it goes into the `if` block. For comparison, use `==` or `===`.

Comment: Those `await`s already await, otherwise you would see `Promise` object logged, that's the direct result of an `async` function. The `await` gets the result from it.

Comment: Do you also read that code, or just write it? If you set a variable to 1, then don't do anything with it, it won't suddenly become 2 two lines later, nor 3 four lines later.

Answer (score 0):

> If i do this function, it will return [] an empty array since it isnt waiting for the if else statement to finish.

No, it won't. That's the point of `async`/`await` syntax, it lets you write asynchronous code using familiar flow control structures. The `async` function this code appears in will return a promise, and the settlement of that promise will depend on what happens in the function's logic. Your code will wait for the promise from `getArray` or `getArray2` to settle, or will continue immediately if `a` isn't `1` or `2` since there's nothing to wait for.

> How do I wait for the if else statement to finsih?

You don't have to, having `await` in the body of the `if`/`else` blocks is sufficient. The function's logic won't progress until the promise from `getArray` or `getArray2` is settled, or (if `a` isn't `1` or `2`) it won't wait because there's nothing to wait for.

Here's an example:

```js
function delay(ms, value) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms, value);
    });
}
async function getArray() {
    await delay(400);
    return [1];
}
async function getArray2() {
    await delay(400);
    return [2];
}
async function example(a) {
    let array;
    if (a === 1) {
        console.log("Calling `getArray`");
        array = await getArray();
    } else if (a === 2) {
        console.log("Calling `getArray2`");
        array = await getArray2();
    } else {
        console.log("Not calling anything, a is not 1 or 2");
        array = [3];
    }
    // Notice that this doesn't happen until/unless
    // `getArray` or `getArray2`'s promise is fulfilled
    console.log(`array is: ${JSON.stringify(array)}`);
}

const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
console.log(`Calling \`example(${value})\`...`);
example(value)
.then(() => {
    console.log("`example` function's promise was fulfilled");
})
.catch(() => {
    // (No code above rejects, but...)
    console.log("`example` function's promise was rejected");
});
```

```html
Run the snippet multiple times to see all three conditions occur (a = 1, 2, and 3).
```

Comment: oh sry i forgot that mine is an if/elif statement instead. so if neither conditions pass, it wont await this ifelse statement. So how do i make sure it waits for the whole thing to end

Comment: @TIMMY123 - What "whole thing" are you waiting for? If you don't have to wait for either `getArray` or `getArray2`, what are you waiting for? It's fine if the function doesn't wait for any promise in one or more branches of the `if`/`else if`/`else`.

Comment: (FWIW, I go into promises and async functions in detail in Chapters 8 and 9 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: just editted my question. Basically I want to wait for these statements to end THEN i change Loading to FALSE which renders my component. So RN my component will render an empty array

Comment: @TIMMY123 - That's fine, your code does all the waiting it needs to do. If there's something to wait for (`getArray`/`getArray2`), it waits for it, and if not, it doesn't and uses the initial `[]` immediately. There's nothing to wait for in the case where `a` is not `1` or `2`.